# Loading a UICollectionView's images asynchronously from Flickr in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UICollectionView in which I've created a class that inherits for UICollectionViewCell. The new class includes an image outlet variable.

The code that I have written thus far displays the cells once all the images have completely downloaded, I would like to load these images asynchronously so each cell gets populated as each individual image gets downloaded from Flickr.

How do I get grand central dispatch to handle this for me?

Here's my code :

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreData

class ImagesCollectionViewController : UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    var mapLat : Double!
    var mapLong : Double!
    let flickrApi = Flickr()
    var imageURLSet = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        // set the location and zoom of the minimap
        let clLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: mapLat, longitude: mapLong)
        let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 2, longitudeDelta: 2)

        mapView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegion(center: clLocation, span: span), animated: false)
        mapView.scrollEnabled = false

        getImages()
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return imageURLSet.count
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return imageURLSet.count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("ImageCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FlickrImageCellViewController

        // This is where the cells are being populated
        let url = NSURL(string: imageURLSet[indexPath.row])
        let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
        let img = UIImage(data: data!)
        cell.imageView.image = img

        return cell
    }

    //Get images from the flickr API and store in array

    func getImages(){

        let parameters : [String : AnyObject] = ["method": Flickr.Consts.GEO_METHOD, "format" : Flickr.Consts.FORMAT, "api_key": Flickr.Consts.API_KEY, "lat" : mapLat, "long" : mapLong, "nojsoncallback" : "1", "per_page" : "21", "extras" : "url_m"]

        flickrApi.performGetRequest(parameters) { (data, error) in


            for record in data as! [AnyObject]{
                if(record["url_m"] != nil){

                    self.imageURLSet.append(record["url_m"] as! String)

                }
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `SDWebImage`, it can help you a lot.

Or you want to download manually, try this

```
let queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
    dispatch_async(queue) { () -> Void in

    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: url)!)
    let img = UIImage(data: data!)!
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        // update your UI
    })
}
```

Hope this can help.

Answer (score 1):

@truongky: your answer is correct. However, in case of reusable cells when images are not stored locally, this would show old image on the reused cells till the new image is downloaded.

Therefore in cellForRowAtIndexPath, the image should be set to nil before the the new image download starts.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("ImageCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FlickrImageCellViewController

    // set image to nil on reused cell
    cell.imageView.image = nil

    // This is where the cells are being populated
    let url = NSURL(string: imageURLSet[indexPath.row])
    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
    let img = UIImage(data: data!)
    cell.imageView.image = img

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Even better would be to reset image in `prepareForReuse` override

Comment: @Mette: Will definitely try that and observe the difference.

Comment: The thing is `prepareForReuse` is used for clearing the cell state before reuse so all things like image reset should be called there but of course it will work the same way you presented here, but it's more clear approach https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionreusableview/1620141-prepareforreuse